# How to disable IDEA auto-closing curvy braces?

Tags: editor, intellij-idea

Previous versions of idea had option to disable auto-typing "}" after "{", but in last version this option is not present.

It does have option "Insert pair '}' on Enter" but it's not what im looking for - in my case idea makes closing '}' immediatly after pressing '{', not 'Enter'.

Comment: What language? Please provide the code fragment to reproduce.

Comment: xml, for example, code for gwt uibinder:
<g:FlowPanel styleName="{}">

Answer (score 10):

There is option 'Insert pair bracket' in Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys. However this option isn't taken into account when '}' in inserted in *.ui.xml files. This problem will be fixed in IDEA 12, thank you for reporting.